# Deploying python scripts

Tags: python

I am a python beginner and I am a little experienced in OO-programming in Java and PHP and also fucntional programming in R . Thus, my question is considering the general usage of python scripts in everyday use-cases.

I want to "learn" how to think/approach a problem that I do experience when facing a situation with my software where a "script" could help me out or improve something.

For instance, I've heard friends talking about their self-made python scripts to evenly mute the audio of movies to avoid loud outliers in explosive scenes, etc. Another example, in my case righ tnow, is to filter out certain pictures with no GPS-time meta information for the timezone in order to sort these fotos in accordance with the others.

I really want to get the essence and recipe based on the aforementioned examples to better integrate Python in my everyday life and get an intuitive feeling for it. (i.e. how would a simple script look like that takes a picture, filters out its meta data, and does something -> where do I have to run the script so I can call the function with these .JPG files as its arguments?).

I would also be glad if some of you could recommend some practical tutorials or literature.

Thank you in advance :)

*P.S. I know it is not a concrete question but rather it is intended to get a glimpse on a wide field of usage and thinking - but I want to get this essential take away that motivates me and shows me the direction.*

Comment: i suggest you try using https://pythonprogramming.net/ or go watch sentdex videos on youtube, helps a bunch, specifically watch the opencv tutorial to better understand images in python,

Comment: you can write small news scraping scripts or something like that and put them in cronjobs to run them regularily - you can use scripts as well and just make them executable files - this way, you can use them anytime you want to!

Comment: thank you so far :)

Comment: *anytime you want to*... Assuming that python interpreter version is installed on the system running a script written elsewhere